# How to use a Snackbar with AndroidX?

Tags: android-snackbar, androidx

I am trying to add a `Snackbar` to my app,

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), 
            R.string.not_found, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
```

but run into this error message:

```
10-05 16:48:24.530 28492-28492/nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket.full E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket.full, PID: 28492
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:188)
        at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:230)
```

I Googled some and it tells me I have to add `com.android.support:design` to my `build.gradle`, but this completely breaks my build, as I am using AndroidX:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'   
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

**Update** I poked a little around and found this XML file that is being inflated (`/extras/android/support/design/res/layout/design_layout_snackbar_include.xml`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
-->

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Snackbar.Message"
            android:maxLines="@integer/design_snackbar_text_max_lines"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left|start"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/snackbar_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/design_snackbar_extra_spacing_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/design_snackbar_extra_spacing_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right|end"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</merge>
```

When just copying that file into my project and opening it in Android Studio, there seems to be something wrong with `?attr/colorAccent`, because when I remove that, the designer shows no errors. But, how to fix all this ... ?

Comment: I haven't worked with the snacker so far, but I started to use androidx recently and I solved all my dependency problems by copying from the sunflower sample app. Because online often the support library is imported which you correctly said won't work like that with androidx. So take a look, this fragment uses the snackbar. The gradle imports are in the build.gradle as usually: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/PlantDetailFragment.kt

Comment: Actually reading your exception, are you sure that the import is the problem? Can you post your xml file? Because the exception does reference the android material snackbar correctly. I think the problem is in that line 41 of the xml file.

Comment: @findusl There is no XML. I just want to be able to use a `Snackbar` instead of a `Toast`, on any layout. I try to use `android.R.id.content` as a generic ID.

Comment: @findusl I'll have a look at that sunflower code.

Comment: Don't know whether it will help you, but this seems to be the xml that fails to inflate: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/res/layout/design_layout_snackbar_include.xml

Comment: Could it be a problem with the android version of your phone? maybe you want to try a simulator with a newer version or something.

Comment: @findusl I tried all kinds of things, a simulator with Android Pie didn't run my code (many other problems), and I did find the XML it is trying to inflate, but I cannot find the problem in it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import

```
com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
```

instead of

```
android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
```

Answer (score 3):

What you should use is this:

`implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06"`

If you're aware on how to configure your dependency in the support way, you can check the Android Developers page on [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)
.
Also, check the most current version, which will probably not be `1.1.0-alpha06` by the point you are reading this.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs if this answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

I added to my build.gradle(Module: app)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

It works fine and my gradle builds successfully.

These are my dependencies:-

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

}

Comment: This makes the project not build anymore. As I understand it, AndroidX is replacing the support libraries.